# Computer automatically mounting install disks when plugging in Mini DisplayPort

Tags: mount, displayport, automount, disk-image

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 running Mojave.  Whenever I plug in a Wacom Cintiq (output VGA converted with a dongle to Mini DisplayPort) my computer mounts a whole bunch of installer images (appear where disks appear in a Finder window), e.x. Inkscape, GIMP, Krita, etc.  I have to manually eject them all.  Then, when I pull out the Mini DisplayPort, all of the images remount.  It's very annoying.

When I used Airplay to connect to a smart TV, the same thing happened, as well as if I go into settings and change screen scaling. I now know this has nothing to do with the Cintiq.

Comment: Odd behaviour, but Wacoms have traditionally been best when connected with the Mac switched off, then they're present at boot. This was certainly true of the older ones, which VGA strongly hints at. …and I presume you mean Mini DP **to** VGA, not the other way round.

Comment: No, VGA output to minidp as I said.  Interestingly, it's not when I plug in the usb just the minidp.  Unfortunately I don't have any other screen or projector to test if it's all minidp, or just the cintiq.

Comment: MacBook Pros from 2015 don't *have* VGA outputs. Also, as we don't know what Cintiq you have & whether it's still supported by Wacom… I know the older Intuos were a merry dance to get working on Mojave, I have one here.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I don't know why I was thinking the cintiq was outputting anything via the vga (only via usb).  Yes, output minidp to vga.  My intuos works fine.  It's just the minidp on the cintiq.

Comment: UPDATE:  When I used airplay to connect to a smart TV, the same thing happened, as well as if I go into settings and change screen scaling.  I now know this has nothing to do with the cintiq.  I don't know if I should start a new thread.

Comment: Quick test - zip all the installers [or archive them somewhere else] Bin the originals. Reboot. idk what's making it do it, but that ought to make it stop ;)

Comment: Do you have any sort of automation software on your Mac? This seems like some weird script triggering when displays are connected, otherwise I wouldn't see how these two things are connected. Perhaps check what kind of apps are in your login items (System Preferences, Users & Groups, <your user>)