# Computer mounts install disks when changing screen resolution Mojave

Tags: install, displayport, resolution, airplay

I have a macbook pro 2015 running Mojave.  Whenever I plug in a screen to minidp, connect to an apple tv using airplay, or change resolution scaling in system preferences (edit: doesn't always happen with changing in system preferences), the system mounts a lot of installers, causes hangups and general problems (sometimes dock disappears), and has crashed my computer at least once.

The exact same thing happens when I unplug the display or go back to standard screen scaling.  This has only happened since I upgraded from Catalina.

EDIT:  The installers are dmg's in my download folders. Mostly free software (e.g. inkscape, GIMP, drawpile, Mischief Free). Mischief and inkscape in particular pull up a EULA agreement like the kind when you install a program, and a finder window with the program and application folder respectively. I could just delete or zip the installers, but it seems that it's a symptom of a bigger problem.

Comment: This is obviously not normal behavior. What sort of installers are they? Where are the installers residing on your disk(s)?

Comment: They are dmg's in my download folders. Mostly free software (e.g. inkscape, GIMP, drawpile, Mischief Free).  Mischief and inkscape in particular pull up a EULA agreement like the kind when you install a program, and a finder window with the program and application folder respectively.  I could just delete or zip the installers, but it seems that it's a symptom of a bigger problem.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your comment to your question as it clarifies the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of  [Computer automatically mounting install disks when plugging in Mini DisplayPort](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426971/computer-automatically-mounting-install-disks-when-plugging-in-mini-displayport)